# Access Tile Information in OpenUI5 / SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

I would like to call a routing function that fires after clicking on a Tile defined in openUI5. Tiles look like these:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.TileContainer/preview

My function fires, but I am having trouble accessing identifiable information about the tile.

Code for the view:

```
<TileContainer
        id="container"
        tileDelete="handleTileDelete"
        tiles="{allalerts>/hits}"
        >
        <StandardTile
            icon="{
                      path: 'allalerts>alert_level',
                      formatter: 'systemstatus.js.TableUtils.formatStatusIcon'
                    }"
            title="{allalerts>hostname}"
            info="{allalerts>ip}" 
            number="{allalerts>site}"
            press="onTileClick"/>
</TileContainer>
```

Code for the press function on the controller:

```
onTileClick : function(evt){
        jQuery.sap.log.error("Calling onTileClick...");
        var oTile = this.getView().byId("container");
        var iIndex = oTile.getInfo(); // Does not work
        jQuery.sap.log.error("Should have an Ip: " + iIndex);
    }
```

The console tells me:

```
oTile.getInfo is not a function
```

It seems like it should work after referencing 
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.StandardTile.html

I know I can get the routing to work once I get this information from the Tile, just need help getting the information. Please let me know if there is any other needed information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the tile title through the evt parameters that is passed to your handler, e.g.: `evt.getSource().getTitle()`

Have a look at [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qahabi/1/edit) to see it in action.

Comment: Fantastic. Works like a charm. Thank you very much. The reason I was calling `this.getView().byId(...)` etc. was because I had done something similar to this when getting information from a Table. This is seems much easier.